# AngularJS: custom orderBy

Tags: angularjs

I have an autocomplete search box.

`<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:search">`

I would like to make it slightly better by sorting the results based on the the name of the items.

```
item1 {name:'applePy'}
item2 {name:'pineApple'}
item3 {name:'application'}
item4 {name:'anApple'}
item5 {name:'apple'}
```

With the current implementation when I write `appl` in the search box the result will be shown as follow:

```
anApple
apple
applePy
application
pineApple
```

But I would like the result to be ordered according to the inserted `appl` like:

```
apple
applePy
application
anApple
pineApple
```

The difference between the two ordering is that in this example the result is ordered according to the search string `appl` and the the rest of the result alphabetically.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two orderings.

Comment: can you use lodash and sort your result..

Comment: @Ericson578, see the edited part.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for search to display the results of the items start with search character in ASC order? If so, you can do this by adding a new method:

```
$scope.startsWith = function (source, target) {
    return source.toLowerCase().indexOf(target.toLowerCase()) === 0;
}
```

Then change your DIV as:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:search:startsWith">
```

If your intention is to list all the search results of "startsWith" and append the rest at the bottom in ASC order. You have to write a custom filter. [See docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)